# How to write a source description under the loaded picture?

Tags: graphics

I loaded a picture with screen capture from a PDF book, besides giving the title of this picture, I also need to cite the source of it. How should I do this? I tried put the source in the

```
\captions{}
```

But looks aweful, and can't make line break. Please anyone tell me how to do this in a proper way.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want the source to be displayed?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `\caption*` command provided by the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to typeset information
without label and without entry in the list of figures (tables). A little example assuming you are using the floating `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\includegraphics{name}
\caption*{Source: some source}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also simply write the source text:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\includegraphics{name}\par
Source: some source
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```