# Add source to figure caption

Tags: floats, captions

How can I add a source to a figure? I need to add `\ref`, `\cite` or just free text. Something like that:

```
\begin{figure} [ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{res/figure.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \source{\ref{},\cite{} or free Text}
  \label{fig:gliederung}
\end{figure}
```

Should give me:

[image: Result]

The source shouldn't appear in `\listoffigures`.

Comment: Have you tried `\caption[Caption]{Caption. Source: here the source of the picture}`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The source could be put inside the caption. LaTeX puts the caption in one line, if it fits there. This can be prevented by `\hspace{\linewidth}` in the following example. When LaTeX tests the width by putting it in a `\hbox`, then `\hspace` is taken into account. LaTeX concludes that the caption does not fit into one line and by setting it in several lines, the line break is executed and the white space right after it (`\hspace{\linewidth}`) is ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{%
    #1%
    \\\hspace{\linewidth}%
    \textbf{Source:} #2%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [ht]
  \centering
  \captionsource{Caption}{ref, cite or free Text}
  \label{fig:gliederung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively package `caption` provides an option `singlelinecheck`, where the testing for fitting into a line can be disabled, using possible multi-line mode always.

Comment: What is the purpose of the asterisk (*) just after the command \newcommand ?

Comment: @Randerson If a macro is defined via the star form `\newcommand*`, then the arguments must not contain empty lines or `\par` tokens. Omit the star, if you expect caption titles to contain paragraphs. Otherwise, TeX is able to throw an error message earlier, if the user has forgotten the closing curly brace of the argument.

Answer (score 62):

I know it makes a lot of time from this post but I had the same problem and found the solution you where looking for. I will post it just in case someone founds it useful.

I took the idea from Gonzalo Medina's post [A: How to write a source description under the loaded picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58300/33066).

**Solution:** load the `caption` package (i.e. write `\usepackage{caption}` at the preamble of your document) and add this line:

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Source: {#1}} }
```

**How to use it:** The way I defined this command, it couldn't be more intuitive:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{./imageName}
    \caption{Caption of the image.} \label{imageLabel}
    \source{Source of the image.}
\end{figure}
```

**How it works:** The added line creates a new command `\source{}` with a single input parameter (*your source*). The `*` in `\caption*{}` prevents the figure caption to be accounted for LaTeX and shown in `\listoffigures` In fact if you type:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{./imageName}
    \caption{Caption of the image.}\label{imageLabel}
    \caption*{Source: Source of the image.}
\end{figure}
```

**Style modification:**

I personaly like having all my sources aligned to the right, so I usually define the command above like that:

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\hfill Source: {#1}} }
```

Also the vertical spacing between Caption and Source can be modified adding a `\vspace{}` command like that:

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\vspace{-3pt} \caption*{ Source: {#1}} }
```

([+] value will add space and [-] value will reduce it)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I believe this more elegant way of achieving this, plus one for that and of course the nice explanation too.

Comment: @Xavi in connection with the answer, how can I reduce the spacing between caption and source? I am using Memoir, but I do not think that it matters in the circumstances.

Comment: Hi @RobertoGozzoli, I guess you mean the vertical spacing between caption and source. I've never used Memoir so I can't assure this answer will work for you. I would just add \vspace{##pt} and play with the value ## to get the space you desire ([+] values will add space while [-] values will reduce it). For me -3pt has been enough. Less than that it overlaps with the Caption. (I will add the response to your question at the post, in "Style modification").

Comment: @Xavi If I want to align my sources to the left what should I use instead of \hfill?

Comment: @Great try just deleting it:
`\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{ Source: {#1}} }`

Comment: Do make sure you use `\usepackage{caption}` at the start of your document! I skipped over that part the first time and it started displaying the star and doing other weird things. Leaving this here in case someone else forgets; maybe they'll see this comment.

Comment: I encountered the same problem like @ProQ. This [comment by Axel Sommerfeldt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310116/why-is-caption-not-working#comment753850_310116) proved to be rather enlightening.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ProQ and @Mr. Tao! I made some changes to better explain how to load the `caption` package.

Comment: Great answer, but somehow this is not working with Beamer. Anyone ran into the same problem?

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeSalomé ! I'm not an expert with `beamer` but I can confirm the above solution does not work with this document class. 

A workaround could be: 
`\newcommand{\source}[1]{\hfill\textbf{Source:} {#1} }` 

This is definitely not a solution; I am sure a nicer command can be defined to use the exame same style `\caption` uses when printing "Figure".  However, it can be used as a workaround until someone provides a better solution (I will try if I have time).

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé  `Beamer` does not like `figure` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative command that could be used for achieving similar results based on @Xavi's answer could look like that:

```latex
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\captionwithsource}[2]{
    \caption{#1}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \caption*{Źródło: {#2}}
}
```

Then when one needs a caption with source one can use a command `\captionwithsource{Caption text}{Source text}` otherwise normal `\caption{Caption text}`. The benefit of that command is that you don't have 2 separate commands to use.

One can also rename the command to whatever they want as I understand that `captionwithsource` can be quite a mouthful. :)

Additionally in my solution instead of using negative `\vspace` with hardcoded value I've decided to use `\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}` which should look just fine for the most font sizes. (Given that one changes it using `\captionsetup[font=<size>]` command.)

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\newcommand{\captionwithsource}[2]{
    \caption{#1}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \caption*{Source: {#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \captionwithsource{This is a table}{https://example.com/}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Lorem ipsum dolor & Lorem ipsum & dolor sit amet \\
        \hline
        1                          & 2           & 3              \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
    \captionwithsource{This is a figure}{https://example.com/}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Results of MWE]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, as usual here, show a short compilable TeX code for a fast proof of your solution!