# Create a custom figure/image source list

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, memoir

I've reviewed the answers at [Add source to figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95029/54029) question and tried to adapt them for what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately I can't get the result I'm looking for. What I am trying to do is create a source command where I can enter the source of the figure but that it does not show up under the figure caption as in the linked question but remains invisible at this point. I would like to create a `listof` environment that I can use in an appendix that would be able to refer back to the figure number and contain the source description. My reason for this is that I'm writing a Humanities thesis and the source description of some of the images from Archives can be quite long.

Below is a MWE (I'm using memoir class) of what I have tried so far but the problem I have is that the caption shows under the figure and nothing shows in my `listof` environment.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}

\newcommand*{\source}{}
\newcommand{\listsourcename}{Picture sources}
\newlistof{listofsources}{los}{\listsourcename}
\newlistentry{source}{los}{0}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[A figure]{A longer image description}
\source{Source of the image.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Another figure]{Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Again Another figure]{Again Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image again.}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\listofsources

\end{document}
```

What I would like is not to have the source caption under the figure but a listing that would give out the following if the MWE is used.

> **Picture Sources**
>
> 1.1: Source of the image
>
> 2.1: Source of another image
>
> 2.2: Source of another image again.

Comment: With other words: A list of image sources?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes you could call it that but not to have the usual dots and page number of figure but just the source text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Use `\source{Some text}` to add something to the `los` file.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}

\newcommand{\listsourcename}{Picture sources}
\newlistof{listofsources}{los}{\listsourcename}

\newcommand*{\source}[1]{\addcontentsline{los}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[A figure]{A longer image description}
\source{Source of the image.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Another figure]{Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Again Another figure]{Again Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image again.}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\listofsources

\end{document}
```

**New version**, with `memoir`'s version of `tocloft` emulation (a little bit strange, in my point of view), removing the page number and the dots in the `numberline`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}

\newcommand{\listsourcename}{Picture sources}
\newlistof{listoffiguresource}{los}{\listsourcename}
\newlistentry{figuresource}{los}{0}% 
\setcounter{losdepth}{1}

\renewcommand{\cftfiguresourcedotsep}{1000}
\newcommand*{\source}[1]{\addtocontents{los}{\protect\contentsline{figuresource}{\thefigure:~#1}{}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[A figure]{A longer image description}
\source{Source of the image.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Another figure]{Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[Again Another figure]{Again Another longer image description}
\source{Source of another image again.}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\listoffiguresource

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to have the list without the usual dots and page numbers but just have the text of the the `\source` command?

Comment: @gman: I thought you would complain about the page numbers ;-) I will update

Comment: I know! Sorry I was a bit quick off the mark with my first comment in reply to your query to the question. Edited it to include that but I'd say you had just posted your answer, that works brilliantly by the way.

Comment: @gman: I've added a memoir solution