# Problems with references to figures and tables

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing

I am finishing my course conclusion work writing using LaTeX, and insert the images I used standard codes, such as

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{lixeoutroa}
\caption{.....}
\label{li(x)exlnx}
\end{figure}
```

This compiling correctly, this all normal, but I do not know how do I put the references in the figure below the figure of the name, I wanted it to be placed (very close) the references of the figure or table without appearing in the list of figure later.

Sorry for writing, do not speak English, I use the translator.
It is also the first time I have any questions TeX here, always use questions in mathematics, then also excuse the way of writing.

Comment: I'm afraid the expression "the references in the figure below the figure of the name" is a bit difficult to understand. Please explain in more detail what you mean by "references in the figure"? Is it maybe a legend, or a source attribution you're trying to get displayed? Please advise.

Comment: i think that what you mean is that you want some additional text below the caption within the scope of the figure.  you can just enter ordinary text following the caption (and label, although that doesn't make a difference, as long as the label is after the caption), and it will be set below the graphic and the caption (and move with the figure as it floats), but it won't go into the list of figures. only the caption will go into the list of figures.

Comment: Suggestions for adding sources to captions of figures can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95029/89098

Answer (score 2):

Well, you gave no MWE so your question is not very clear.

I guess with your "references of the figure" you mean a text explaining where you got the immage, for example a article or book.  In my example code I just wrote some text, please change it to what you need ...

Please see the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

test See figure~\ref{fig:example} and figure~\ref{fig:exampleb}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example Image from package \texttt{MWE}}
  Example for an reference text
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

test See figure~\ref{fig:examplec} and figure~\ref{fig:exampleb}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Example Image b from package \texttt{MWE}}
  Example for an reference text with more text to show the effect before 
  the command \texttt{label}.
  \label{fig:exampleb}
\end{figure}

test See figure~\ref{fig:exampleb} and figure~\ref{fig:examplec}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example Image c from package \texttt{MWE}}
  \label{fig:examplec}
  Example for an reference text with more text to show the effect.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The "Example for an reference text ..." I wrote between command `\caption` and `\label` or see the last figure after `\label`.

In the list of figures you have only the captions, where the images are printed you see the additional reference text as I think you wished ...

See the list of figures:

[image: list of figures]

See a page with two images with "reference text":

[image: images with reference text]