# How to insert "source" below image

Tags: floats, captions, positioning

I have to mention the source of the image that I am using in my text.

[image]

How can I write the source below any image just like its shown in the above figure? I don't want to mention the source alongside caption. I am using following code for inserting images and it would be helpful if anyone can tell the codes for writing source which is compatible with this one:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\caption{Letter e}
\end{figure}
```

I have seen [Add source to figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95029/add-source-to-figure-caption) but it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{copyrightbox}
%%%% figure-copyright
    \usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
           {Source: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}

    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
or with `stackengine`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
\def\stackalignment{r}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
           {\scriptsize%
            Source: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
\caption{Image with copyright}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful solution. Is it possible to have the source text box to have the same size of the image? i.e. If the URL is longer than the image width so it goes to a new line?

Comment: @CarloCorradini, yes. Just try.  But you in such cases instead ˙url˙use ˙xurl` which better handle to split it into more lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `xurl`. Unfortunately it does not work: https://imgur.com/Czd9omu

Comment: I'm using your solution in a `wrapfigure` environment and the code is the same as yours

Comment: If you some problem with this, please ask new question, that more  people will able to help you.

Comment: Thanks again. New question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/673643/221716

Answer (score 12):

Set your image in a `tabular` that has a single `r`ight-aligned column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imagesource}[1]{{\footnotesize Source: #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{} }
    \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image} \\
    \imagesource{Image A}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```