# Image source below image and longer than its width

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure, stackengine, xurl

This is a follow-up to the answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412010/221716

As with the original question, I'd like to include the source text under the image. However, the URL is longer than the image's width, and the environment is a `wrapfigure`.

Latex source:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}
  {r}{.25\textwidth}
  \centering
  \def\stackalignment{r}\stackunder{ %
    \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-b} %
  }{\tiny Source: \url{https://www.example.org/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/long/url}}
  \caption{My Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As a result, the URL does not take into account the width of the environment. As a result, the picture is misaligned, and the URL is not wrapped inside the appropriate width:
[image: Result]

Surprisingly, removing `\stackalignment{r}` correctly wraps the URL but removes the picture:
[image: Result_2]

**Is it feasible to have the picture and the source aligned and wrapped correctly? Furthermore, because the text is so small, may the vertical space of the URL be reduced?**
Thanks

Comment: the answer you link to is so nice and shows a complete example and uses a graphic that is generally available. One can directly copy&paste and try. Why do you drop all this and make your code untestable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Code Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf,
            justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{%
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}} % remove superfluous vertical space above/below wrapfigure

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.25\textwidth}
\def\stackalignment{r}\stackunder{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{image.png} %
    }{\scriptsize 
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{% <... needed
    Source: \url{https://www.example.org/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/long/url}}
   }
  \caption{Caption of wrapfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Only one doubt: what is the purpose of `etoolbox` and `BeforeBeginEnvironment`? Thanks

Comment: @CarloCorradini, they insert before each `wrapfig` command `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}`, whic remove vertical space above/below figure. For test delete this part of code and see difference. See edited answer.