# \caption* command causes wrong reference in List of Figures for subfigures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, subcaption

I have created a custom `\source` command which places a second caption under a figure using the `\caption*` command (see [Xavi's answer on this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95029/add-source-to-figure-caption)). Also I have enabled the `list` option of the `subcaption` package to include subfigures in the List of Figures.

However, when using the `\source` command for a figures containing subfigures the caption of the subfigures are wrongly placed in the List of Figures, see the following example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setcapindent{1em} 
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{ {\small Source: {#1}}} }

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{Subcaption Test}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First Figure}
\end{figure}
Some text
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First Subfigure}
        \label{fig:first}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Second subfigure}
        \label{fig:second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \source{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
    \caption{Second figure with two subfigures}
\end{figure}

Subfigures \ref{fig:first} and \ref{fig:second} have the correct reference but appear wrong in the list of figures.

\end{document}
```

The example produces the following output.

[image: Output of the MWE]

The two subfigures in the second figure are incorrectly listed under the first figure. However, the labels still correctly refer two 2a and 2b. Therefore I don't understand what causes the problem.

Can somebody explain this behaivour and tell me how to fix it? Or should I not be using `\caption*` command to create sources?

Note: I have also included the Koma-Script command `\setcapindent{1em}`, but I don't think that causes the problem.

Also, since this is my first question and I am fairly new to the Latex world I would be gratefull for any advice regarding asking questions on tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to your defined `\source` command. If you place the source command below the `\caption` in the figure environment, then you will get expected output. However, if you want to put the source ahead of the caption, then you can use the `\addcontentsline` command (see section 2.3 of the LaTeX Companion 2nd edition for more info).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setcapindent{1em} 
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{ {\small Source: {#1}}} }

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{Subcaption Test}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First Figure}
\end{figure}
Some text
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First Subfigure}
        \label{fig:first}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Second subfigure}
        \label{fig:second}
    \end{subfigure}
    %-----------------------------added---------------------------
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{%
        \protect\numberline {\getrefnumber{fig:sec}}Second figure with two subfigures} 
    %--------------------------------------------------------------
    \source{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
    \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{} % <-------- added
    \caption{Second figure with two subfigures}
    \label{fig:sec}
\end{figure}

Subfigures \ref{fig:first} and \ref{fig:second} have the correct reference but appear wrong in the list of figures.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. However, I find this approach a bit cumbersome. Of course, one could define a command `\sourcecaption{source}{caption}{label}` but I would like to maintain the flexibility of the `\caption` and `\label` commands. This leads me to the conclusion, that using `\caption*` for creating a source is not the right approach. How can I redefine the `\source` command to work as expected?

Comment: As an extra note, is this behaviour of the `\caption*` command even correct? According to the captions manual, the `\caption*` command typesets the caption without label and without entry in the list of figures. Is this a bug?

Comment: @MarvinStrebel Yes, it's cumbersome for something seemingly straightforward. In fact, I would insert the source as simple text above the caption and to get consistent spacing I might use `\vspace`.

Comment: @MarvinStrebel I think `\caption*` is working correctly. It didn't add any content in the LOF rather due to the use of both `\caption` and `\caption*` command, things were messed up. Someone experienced enough might explain the behavior better (I am a beginner).