# How to write source description under longtables?

Tags: captions, longtable

I want to be able to add the source information below `figures` and `tables` ( `longtables` included). I have used the idea provided in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58296/how-to-write-a-source-description-under-the-loaded-picture/), but it gives the following error for `longtables`:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign
```

Is it possible to fix and have a single command that would for those enviroments?

Here is a minimal code to reproduce it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{
 \vspace{1ex}\caption*{\textbf{Source:} {#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Test - Table}\label{t:test}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\toprule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\source{Test Test}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\caption{Test - Longtable} \label{lt:test} \\
\toprule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\source{Test longtable 123}
\end{longtable}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test123.}\label{fig-img-a}
 \source{Test image.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}Source …}` as the last row of the table?

Comment: It compiles fine without the `\vspace{1ex}` and with `\\ ` after `\source{Test longtable 123}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `longtable` environment does not like the combination of `\vspave` plus `\caption`, at least not without an extra `\\` between them.

Solution: Do not use `\vspave` but let `\caption` do the skip, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{
 \captionsetup{skip=1ex,position=b}%
 \caption*{\textbf{Source:} {#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Test - Table}\label{t:test}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\toprule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\source{Test Test}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\caption{Test - Longtable} \label{lt:test} \\
\toprule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\source{Test longtable 123} \\
\end{longtable}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Test123.}\label{fig-img-a}
 \source{Test image.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```